# Android Studio Asynctask Alternative

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm new to Android Development, and I've run into this problem that I haven't found a solution for.

It starts off first with going to a webservice api for login. From there if the login is successful it executes to 2 functions for the actually data it needs, stores in sqlite and then proceeds to next activity.  All 3 api requests are using AsyncTask and from what I understand my Activity is actually running faster than my "doInBackground" background thread.  I want to know the path or what i should look into.  I've read posts about using sleep, and read posts about how that is bad to do. I want to get the json data i need, store it, and use it immediately. I think i'm suppose to find away to connect directly and use a progress bar to get the data.  Keep in mind, it's not a lot of data, but it's enough to stall my application.

Comment: I think i may have found a lead using Android Volley Jsonrequest

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what a ProgressBar has to do with retrieving data from a server but if you're looking for AsyncTask alternatives (particularly for HTTP calls) you can look at these frameworks (you'll probably only want to pick one):

1. [Square's Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
2. [Google's Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Either one will make your life a lot easier when it comes to making HTTP requests. Their own documentation explains how to use them pretty well so I'm not going to go into how to use it here.

If you're looking for a native, lower level `AsyncTask` alternative, have a look at [AsyncTaskLoaders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html). The `AsyncTaskLoader` essentially does exactly the same thing as an `AsyncTask` but they live within the life cycle of the Activity or Fragment so your code tends to be less error prone.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've figured out how to use Google's Volley and I like it a lot more than asyncTask.  I'm still having the same issue though with the timing.  After login, I'm making 2 api requests for data then storing them into sqlite database, then proceeding to a dashboardActivity.  The problem is that the data is not in the database at the time the dashboard starts, (i think it shows up maybe a few seconds too late).  Any thoughts/suggestions?